# Executing JS before DomContentLoaded?

Tags: javascript, optimization, pagespeed

I have a question concerning the attached image namely **WHY** according to this graph 'Run JS' is fired before 'Build DOM' while many sources claim that JS requires 'DomContentLoaded' ?

According to this graph JS is fired before DomContentLoaded.... :(

[image]

Comment: Where does this diagram come from?

Comment: if your javascript is not conditioned by something like document.ready() in jQuery or window.onload() then it will fire as soon as it is processed. the two before mentioned functions make it wait until the content is loaded so that you won't end up trying to do something with content that does not exists yet.

Comment: ...so from what you are saying, JavaScript CAN fire before DOM is ready. But there is the article here (https://medium.com/@luisvieira_gmr/understanding-the-critical-rendering-path-rendering-pages-in-1-second-735c6e45b47a) which says ""Javascript is a powerful tool that can manipulate both the DOM and CSSOM, so to execute Javascript, the browser has to wait for the DOM, then it has to download and parse all the CSS files, get to the CSSOM event and only then finally execute Javascript." -> apparently the iformation in this article is true..